# Отслеживание в asynctask ответа сервера, тайм-аута соединения. Взаимодействие с UI

Tags: android

В приложении через AsyncTask забирается JSON с сервера (скрипт php).

Как прервать AsyncTask в случаях:

1. Ответ сервера не 200 (перегружен, недоступен и т.п.).
2. Таймаут ответа сервера превышает 5сек `boolean timeResponse;`.
3. Отсутствует и мобильное интернет-соединение, и wi-fi (значка нет совсем).

И уже соответственно в UI выполнять действия в зависимости от ситуации?

**Собственный класс AsyncTask:**

```
public class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<ApiGetJsonData, String, JSONArray> {

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(ApiGetJsonData... params) {
        return params[0].GetJsonData();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray){
        // ... обрабатываем полученный jsonArray
    }
}
```

**ApiGetJsonData:**

```
public class ApiGetJsonData extends MainActivity {

    private String url;             // Путь к скриптам
    int status;                     // Статус ответа сервера
    int timeOut = 5000;             // Задержка ответа сервера
    boolean timeResponse;           // Ответ сервера по таймауту
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;     // Массив данных из ответа сервера
    HttpEntity httpEntity = null;   // Ответ сервера

// Конструктор для url
public ApiGetJsonData(String region){
    this.url = "http://../srcipt.php?region=" + region;
}

public JSONArray GetJsonData(){

    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        this.status = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        this.timeResponse = InetAddress.getByName(url).isReachable(timeOut);

        if (!timeResponse) {
             // .. ОТВЕТ СЕРВЕРА ДОЛЬШЕ 5 СЕКУНД
        }

        if (status == 200){             // Если нормальный ответ сервера (код 200)

            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            String entityResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(entityResponse);
            Log.e("Данные с сервера (JSON): ", entityResponse);

        } else if (status == 503) {     // Если сервер перегружен/отключен
            // ... ЧТО-ТО ВИДИМО НАПИСАТЬ ТУТ
        } else {                        // Если пришел другой ответ сервера
             // ... И ТУТ ...
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.e("Ответ сервера: ", "status");

    return jsonArray;

}
```

**Вызываю AsyncTask так:**

```
new GetDataTask().execute(new ApiGetJsonData(region));
```

Также хотелось бы услышать ответы тех, кто применял уже подобное в своих проектах:

1. Какие еще ответы сервера следует обрабатывать?
2. Бывает ли ситуация, когда соединение с интернетом отсутствует (нет сети, совсем нет, в подвале на глубине 100 метров). Как в этом случае приложению избежать краша?

Comment: @Чекист вы что раньше писали по C#?

Answer (score 1):

Передавать в AsyncTask экземпляр Activity как параметр - это извращение. Прям-таки БДСМ. Перенесите метод GetJsonData вовнутрь AsyncTask, и все ваши проблемы решатся. Все ваши проблемы из-за того, что вы не можете получить доступ к объекту AsyncTask из метода GetJsonData.

И еще:

1. Методы должны называться с маленькой буквы (**G**etJsonData).
2. Так делать ни в коем случае, ни при каких обстоятельствах нельзя: *new ApiGetJsonData(region)*. Нельзя самому вызывать конструктор Активити. Это должна делать только система!
3. Стоит обрабатывать одинаково все ответы от сервера, кроме 200.
4. Естественно, бывает ситуация, когда нет доступа в интернет. Избежать краша, как и в любом другом случае поможет `try{...}catch()`. Еще можно системными методами проверить предварительно подключение. [Тык](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20check%20internet%20connection&es_th=1).

Comment: по п2. - на чем основаны Ваши доводы? Это РАБОТАЕТ )

Comment: Это не экземпляр Activity, это класс со своим конструктором и методом.
1. Букву исправил, опечатка.
2. см выше
3. Про тайм-аут так и не понятно
4. Спасибо за совет

Comment: @Чекист,

>Про тайм-аут так и не понятно

Просто дополнительно отлавливайте

    org.apache.commons.httpclient.ConnectTimeoutException